# Create object link to different DOORS project

Tags: ibm-doors

Apparently, links are not supposed to connect objects of modules which reside in different projects. I failed trying to create some, both manually as well as DXL-based.

My script

```
Module modA = edit("/foo/foo", true, false)
Module modB = read("/bar/bar", false)

Object objA = object(1472, modA)
Object objB = object(781, modB)

objA -> objB
```

The script prints the error:

```
-R-E- DXL: <Line:78> A linkset pairing restriction prevents the creation of links 
from /foo/foo to /bar/bar.
No link will be created.
-I- DXL: execution halted
```

Is there any trick to bypass that and create a link using magic or hidden features?

Answer (score 1):

That is not a restriction for linking across Projects. This error is telling your two things:

1. There is no Linkset defined between the two documents specified.
2. The setting for `Mandatory` linksets is turned on in the document you are linking from.

I HIGHLY recommend leaving the `Mandatory` linksets turned on for all modules. Linksets give you the ability to organize the type of links that you are creating. If you turn this off, users can create linksets from anything to anything with any linkset they define on the fly. I have seen this cause big problems at different companies because you can't easily identify what links you want to analyze for traceability.

We have instead created a handful of link modules that we use for all links in our database. For Example:

```
Traceability Links
Reference Links
Glossary Links
etc...
```

This way, in any document we can reuse the same views and filters to view traceability across the Project or Projects. We then set up the linksets to use these link modules only.

Long story short, you need to create a linkset between Module A and Module B in Module A properties.

Comment: I agree with Steve. But, creating links across project boundaries is highly not recommended. Especially if on those projects are working different teams. If you are thinking towards a "requirements reuse" then I recommend another approach.