# Creating a DOORS external link using command line

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd, ibm-doors

I am trying to create a batch file which links a DOORS item to a external file.
I have only managed to find the following thread on stackoverfow but it doesn't help me with external link:
[Create object link to different DOORS project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31201798/create-object-link-to-different-doors-project)
Could I get some help, please :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Could you elaborate this?

What do you mean with "batch file"? A MS Windows batch file (guessing this, according to yout tags)? Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20239531/run-dxl-script-on-the-background-command-line-dxl-doors) to find out how to put DXL code into a working MS Windows batch script. You probably want to create a batch script which takes at least one parameter (the link target).

In DOORS, a link is usually a directed association of two DOORS objects. You seem to try to create such an association between a DOORS object and a file. Is that correct? In this case, you want to use the `ExternalLink` data type.

In case you refer to the `ExternalLink`: external links are used to refer to URLs. If you want to link to a file, you can simply address that file by its URL:

```
ExternalLink el
create(current Object, "Description", "Name", outward, openAsURL, "file://d:/foo.bar", el)

if (null el)
    print "No link created!\n"
else
    print "'" name(el)"' created on " el."Created On" "\n"
```